# Can't publish on Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have just finished and signed the apk through android studio, then I have did a signed apk.  when I am trying to upload the apk to play store I got this error " You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

Comment: And you honestly and publicly declare that the error message is in a format, sentence, spelling and language that prevents you from understanding? Reading and trying to understand the error message, the rest is simple google search... it can be so easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try cross check that you didn't uploaded debug version cross check the following link.
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your sdk or you can run zipalign manually in command line

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Note that zipalign is located inside

> ${sdk.dir}\tools

Link to zipalign:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

Comment: ones i was updated my sdk, and whole my project went down, now i am affraid of this